# Rewrite sql query to pad empty month rows

Tags: mysql, date, join

I have this query i use to get statistics of blogs in our own tracking system.

I use union select over 2 tables as we daily aggregate data in 1 table and keeps todays data in another table.

I want to have the last 10 months of traffic show.. This query does that, but of there is no traffic in a specific month that row is not in the result.

I have previously used a calendar table in mysql to join against to at avoid that, but im simply not skilled enoght to rewrite this query to join against that calendar table.

The calendart table has 1 field called "datefield" which i date format YYY-MM-DD

This is the current query i use

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(`count`),0) as `count`, DATE(`date`) as `date` 
FROM
(
  SELECT  count(distinct(uniq_id)) as `count`, `timestamp` as `date`
  FROM    tracking
  WHERE   `timestamp`  > now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND target_bid = 92
  group by `datestamp`

  UNION ALL

 select sum(`count`),`datestamp` as `date`
  from aggregate_visits
  where `datestamp` > now() -  interval 10 month
  and target_bid = 92
  group by `datestamp`
 ) a
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 select sum(COALESCE(t.`count`,0)),s.date as `date`
 from DateTable s
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM aggregate_visits 
            where `datestamp` > now() -  interval 10 month
            and target_bid = 92) t
  ON(s.date = t.datestamp)
 group by s.date
```

Comment: Works like a charm with a bit of rewrite from your example.. thanks alot